# Live stream data in power apps

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, power-automate

I'm trying to make an app based on an excel file or some other data source but I want the app to live update constantly and change values as and when the data source is updated.

I was looking into using a python back end or something else but this is really slipping my area of knowledge since I know almost nothing about how to work with power stuff

Is this possible to do? How would you go about doing it?

Thanks for any replies!